# How to check validation of template form in ts component file angular 2?

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

I implemented form validation using template form validation in angular 2
And I have to check form validation inside typescript file.
I knew the way when use reactive form validation, but I would like to do it with template form.
for example.

---- type script ----

```
class CreateTourComponent extends MeteorComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
   onSubmit(evt){
     if(!myForm.isValid()){
       alert('not valid submission');
     }else{ 
     ... 
     } 
   }
  ...
}
```

---- template -----

```
<form class="package-form" #myForm="ngForm">

 <button (click) = "onSubmit(evt)" value='submit'></button>
</form>
```

is it possible for template form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**component.html**

```
<form name="myForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(editForm)" #editForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" [(ngModel)]="data.name" required />
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class AppComponent {
    data: any = {};
    onSubmit(myForm: NgForm) {
        if(myForm.valid) {
             console.log('valid form');
        } else {
             console.log('invalid form');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `myForm.****`

```
<form class="package-form" #myForm="ngForm">
 {{myForm.valid}} 
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to check validation inside ts file, is there other way?
Because button for submission is apart from form, not inside form.

Comment: by validation what you mean? custom validation or ? add the relevant  code to post

Comment: no custom validation.
<form ...>
</form>
<button (click)="onSubmit(evt)">
In this case, I have to check validation inside ts file

Comment: but your post has `button` inside the `form`.. ??

Comment: sorry, it was my fault, I fixed post

Comment: what is that you exactly want. can you elaborate?

Comment: I have to check form validation inside typescript file (component)

Comment: go for reactive forms in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153987/discussion-between-whitesnow-and-aravind).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

Then:

```
export class myFormComponent {
   ...
  onSubmit({ value, valid }) {
    console.log(value, valid);
  }

}
```